# Any good open source test management tools ?

Tags: test-management

I am thinking of developing some test management tools, to sit alongside the open source automation tools that I currently use. Primarily for recording manual and automated tests, results and providing reports.

Before I start these from scratch, I am wondering if there are any existing projects that I should consider donating my time to instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test link comes to my mind. I used it long back and have always heard good reviews about it. It has been used on sizable projects in my old workplace and scaled pretty well to ever increasing test artefacts and a large number of users. 
It is in active development and boasts of a substantial user base. Can do pretty much anything considering its open source. here's the link

http://sourceforge.net/projects/testlink/

Comment: I was aware of testlink, I wasn't aware it is open source. It is the sort of thing I am after, but not exactly. I can't put my finger on why ....

Comment: I wonder if it has modularity that would allow you to drop in and out components you want or don't want. Then you can develop modules you do want, but you won't have to start from scratch on it. I personally have never even heard of it, but it might be worth looking in to. At the very least, most open source projects would love experienced people helping with development! :)

Comment: TestLink is OpenSource only. Its good too.

Comment: The only thing I would add about testlink (from experience) is that for our organisation the upgrade path from 1.7.x to later versions appears to be broken due to our use of the requirements feature. We haven't decided yet, but we'll either be moving away from this or biting the bullet and manually  porting data to the latest version and hope it doesn't happen again. Ignoring this, it seems fairly functional and has a lot of good features.

Answer (score 1):

We used [TestiaTarantula](http://www.testiatarantula.com/) - I found it's user interface appealing, and tagging functionality of almost anything very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Other major one I've seen is xStudio.  I've only tried the demo out, never got backing to try a full install.  We are still using good old Quality center at my place of business.  It's at least worth checking out.

http://www.xqual.com/products/xstudio.html